# Faster & easier way to create & edit non-existent files in multiple directories

Tags: files, vim

Let's say I have this tree

```bsh
$ tree
.
├── 1
│   └── notes
├── 2
│   └── notes
├── 3
└── 4

4 directories, 2 files
```

I want to edit the existing `notes` files, as well as create & edit `notes` files in `3` & `4`.

If I use `nvim */notes`, only `1/notes` & `2/notes` are opened.

When I run `touch */notes`, no new `notes` file is created.

Currently, the only way to create & edit new files is to use a `for` loop: `for i in $(ls); do touch $i/notes; done`. However, this is rather long and is a pain to type out.

Is there are faster & easier way to create & edit new files? Bonus if it can be done in a single command and/or is an (n)vim builtin.

Comment: Note: [never do `for i in $(ls)`](https://mywiki.wooledge.org/ParsingLs). You should use `for i in */; do...` instead.

Comment: You can define a short alias (or a function) for the long command `alias n='for i in */; do touch $i/notes; done && nvim */notes'`

Comment: I assume the 2nd `*` in the first touch command is a typo because you never wanted to create files that start with notes and have something at the end. I'm editing your question to fix it. Also in your for loop you are only creating, not modifying so i added a nvim

Comment: So i edited your questions to fix what i assume were oversights that you knew but just forgot to mention in the question. But another question remains: If you will be editing them, why the `touch` ? You could immediately replace every `touch` by `nvim`. It will create the non-existing file. (But you will still have to use the loop)

Comment: @Garo I don't want to put `nvim` in a loop since it'd mean I'd have to close nvim to edit the next file. I want to open all the files in a single nvim instance in multiple buffers.

Answer (score 1):

For this specific case, you can use the shell's `{...}` syntax, to cover a list of alternatives.

```
$ nvim {1,2,3,4}/notes
```

Even more convenient, since they're numbers, you can pass it as a range, which is convenient as you start having tens or hundreds of them, assuming they're numbers in a sequence:

```
$ nvim {1..4}/notes
```

This is not a very general solution and it's not great that it doesn't really check whether the directories actually exist, or use the existing directories as input... But it might be convenient in your specific case.

Other than that, I couldn't really come up with something better than a `for` loop.